# Do a "git diff" between two directories due to website owner making live changes

Tags: php, git, version-control, diff, text-comparison

I have a project I'm working on which I've set up in a git repo.

Since I put my latest version live, the website owner has made some changes to the working/content by overwriting it directly.

Obviously these changes were made outside of version control. I suppose I could overwrite the entire contents of my repo, then commit. That *should* work... but I don't really like the idea of doing that, especially if there's been any replacement of correct code/html-structure with stuff that's incorrect or bad practice.

What I'd like to do is dump the website from live into another directory and do a recursive diff so I can only overwrite those files which have changed (any correct any issues if there are any)

Comment: Can't you just run `git status` to see what's changed?

Comment: As in if I just overwrite what's in my git repo, then run git status? that's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As in if I just overwrite what's in my git repo, then run git status?

No, you don't have to overwrite anything.

You can do a diff between:

- the index representing your site in its latest versioned state (in the git repo)
- a dump of the current live site (a copy done in a different folder, not under version control)

You can then do (using [`git` options](http://git-scm.com/docs/git)) a:

```
git diff --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/dump .
```

You actually can execute that command from any folder: it will look for the git index and for the right working tree.

---

The [OP Tom Busby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786580/tom-busby) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848269/do-a-git-diff-between-two-directories-due-to-website-owner-making-live-changes/23848396?noredirect=1#comment36980898_23848396):

> In the end I solved it by simply overwriting the `.git` folder in my dump directory with the one from my git repo and running `git diff`.

Comment: I'm getting this error:

Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

Comment: @TomBusby That is because you didn't pass the `.git` folder path of your repo: `--git-dir` must reference the `/path/to/your/repo/.git` (the `/.git` at the end is important)

Comment: Still having the same problem:

 git diff --git-dir=/home/tom/Git/vikingchallenge/.git --work-tree=/home/tom/Git/www/.git .
Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

Comment: Tried it with and without the /.git on the end of www

Comment: @Tom The work tree must not have the .git, only git-dir ends with .git. And make sure both paths exist.

Comment: @tom that is what I meant by "make sure both paths exist": if you delete folders, I confirm that won't work well...

Comment: @Tom and the /path/to/repo I mention in my answer must be a path to a git repo.

Comment: You just said the work tree must not have a .git. I just got rid of it and it still doesn't work, the paths exist. /path/to/repo is a git repo

Comment: I've tried absolute paths, relative paths. I've tried pwd outside of both dirs mentioned, and I've tried it inside the repo, and inside the work tree. Same error every time ----- Path to repo is a git repo, path to dump isn't.

Comment: @TomBusby the idea is: you specify a git repo (`/path/to/repo/.git`), and a place where you have that repo content (`/path/to/dump`, no `.git` at all): you can then compare both. Both paths are absolute. But both paths are *different* paths.

Comment: tried that, it didn't work. In the end I solved it by simply overwriting the .git folder in my dump directory with the one from my git repo and running git diff.

Comment: @TomBusby Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: But yeah man, sorry, I'm going to have to untick it. I've followed your instructions, and tried every permutation I can think of to make it work and it doesn't work. I do appreciate the help, it's just if someone else comes along, it shouldn't be ticked as if it works.

Comment: @TomBusby that is why I also have included your conclusion. To avoid unticking ;)

Answer (score 2):

VonC's answer is excellent, but I believe you could also just use the `diff` command (a built-in command on most operating systems). This would also ensure that "gitignored" files were diffed (though VonC's might already do that).

Assuming the website in `/www/mysite` and a fresh clone in `/git/mysite` you could just do:

`diff /www/mysite /git/mysite`

Answer (score -1):

Yes We can compare two directories very easily

simply using this command on Shell/Terminal

git diffdir     any-branch-name     any-other-branch-name